# interpreting multinomial logistics regression coefficients into odds

Tags: multinomial-logit

I am using sklearn logistic regression to predict age (numeric) vs gender (male, female, non-binary) -

the below are intercept

[ 18.5455613   -1.83610814 -14.10055903]

these are the coefficients of age

array([[-3.45772499], - male
[ 0.19487919], - non binary
[ 2.22982158]]) - female

how to calculate the probability from above info?

Comment: The formula for the probabilities can be found [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/162914/7071) in the second equation.

Comment: thanks. do you know any library in python to directly give the probability? plz share if u know

Comment: Try pred = log_reg.predict(Xvars)